# Eclipse RCP: add view to "window->show view" menu

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I have to extend an e3 application.
I defined a new perspective with 2 views (as parts) in a fragment.e4xmi.
I added the tag "View" to the parts to show them in the "window->show view->others" menu (does what was expected).
What does **not** work is adding the tag `persp.viewSC:*myViewsID*` to add the view to the shortlist. [ShowViewMenu finds the tags and adds them to the shortcut-list but they don't show up, because the `IViewRegistry` finds no `IViewDescriptor`.

(The tag `persp.perspSC:*otherPerspectiveID*` to show the other perspectives however does work)

I know that this is a bad mixture of e3 and e4 but i thought since the views are already showing up and only need to get from the "others" category to the first hierarchy levelof the menu it should be quite easy.